# Transform the text of python logger

Tags: python, logging

Is there an in built functionality in the python logging module that transforms its output text? im currently logging data that can contain hexadecimal or non ascii characters that are not properly displayed when i log the output to a file.

my current solution so to transform the text before i put it into the logger, but ill prefer to do the transformation once rather than every log line.

e.g.

```py
Logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
Logger.textTransformation([("non_ascii_char", "replacement"),("non_ascii_char_2", "replacement")])
```

Comment: You could log the reprs instead?   `logger.info("spam %r", some_string)`

Comment: @snakecharmerb hi, logging the reprs isn't too readable because i get loads of \x1d1\x1d etc across the text.  Basically what i want is to transform hex characters/non-ascii characters into something readable e.g. "Name\x1d\x1dSam--> Name++Sam"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use a custom logging.Formatter. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37901298/7637870) for a succinct example of subclassing logging.Formatter to change the text formatting behavior.